# dump files from bash script in different directory from where python script ran it

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a python script with the following code.

```
Python script: /path/to/pythonfile/
Executable: /path/to/executable/
Desired Output Path: /path/to/output/
```

My first guess...

```
import subprocess

exec = "/path/to/executable/executable"
cdwrite = "cd /path/to/output/"

subprocess.call([cdwrite], shell=True)
subprocess.call([exec], shell=True)
```

This dumps all the files in `/path/to/pythonfile/`...
I mean this makes sense, but I'm not sure what 'ego' to assume - that of my what my python code sees or that of the shell script, I thought it was running *in* shell so if I cd in shell, it will cd to the directory required and dump the output there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is the two commands are being executed independent of one another.  What you want to do is cd into the directory, then execute.

```
subprocess.call(';'.join([cdwrite, exec]), shell=True)
```

Are you running the script in the same directory as the python file?  With what you have right now the files should be outputed to the directory that you ran the python script in (which may or may not be the directory with the script).  This also means that if the path you give `cd` is relative, it will be relative to the directory you ran the python script in.

Answer (score 0):

You should change directory within the same command:

```
cmd = "/path/to/executable/executable"
outputdir = "/path/to/output/"
subprocess.call("cd {} && {}".format(outputdir, cmd), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cwd` argument:

```
from subprocess import check_call

cmd = "/path/to/executable/executable"
check_call([cmd], cwd="/path/to/output")
```

Note: don't use `shell=True` unnecessarily.